# Redshift Operations User Permissions

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm looking to build a set of permissions for an operations team that will handle permissions across the cluster and add/alter users. However, it appears to me that this can only be done by a superuser.

Can anyone confirm that if I want a user that can create users it will also be able to drop schemas and databases as well? I assume I'm missing something because that statement sounds a bit ludicrous.

Thanks!

Comment: There are some system defined roles which you can use, e.g. `sys:secadmin`. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_roles-default.html